# Integrating Google Analytics Report for Behavior Targeting

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to retrieve visitor behavior data from Google Analytics on my site. For example, detecting New Visitor or Returning Visitor so i can manage different Site Messages. If i can get the user data metrix, i think we could do a lot of stuff for marketing purpose

I know we can implement our own cookies, but what we had in Google Analytics is more than enough if its accessible, why re-invent the wheel ?

So hope you guys can give me insight if my inquiry is applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this with Google Analytics.

You can look at tools such as Google Optimize or Optimizely for personalization, A/B testing.